# Synchronizing two Mercurial branches

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I sometimes need to "synchronize" my current (named) branch A with another branch B, i.e. merge B into A and then merge A into B.

[image]

This is how I currently do this in TortoiseHg:

- Update to tip of A (if necessary)
- Right-click tip of B, "Merge with local..."
- Update to tip of B
- Right-click tip of A, "Merge with local..."
- Update to tip of A

Is there an easier/faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Do it in CLI? `hg up ...`+ `hg merge ...` twice?

Comment: @LazyBadger That would require knowing and typing the branch names or revision numbers, right?

Comment: Yes, but... you have|can to know branch-names, for 2-branches repo (I think) getting "other" branchname can be automated with revsets|templating, for fully automatic sync complex alias can be created, even in Windows (and your sync will be one command in console)

Comment: I think it is possible to write a little plugin. It can read all branches (with commits last month, ex) and let user to choose other branch from list.